# What's the advantage to use Datagram Channel compared to Datagram Socket

Tags: java, sockets, io, udp, nio

I'm trying to optimize a UDP server to handle more throughput, it's based on Java IO Datagram Socket(not NIO).
when this UDP server receives a UDP packet, it needs to process this packet, and send the processed data to background resources, then responds the client.
Currently this server will allocate a thread for each incoming packet to process.

I've read some articles, I understood that
for some cases, for example, a chat server based TCP:
that needs to manage thousands of open connections simultaneously, which each only send a little data, implementing the server in NIO is probably an advantage.
Very few threads could handle lots of connections (Thread Per Request), because only a few of connections send requests to server at a given time point. So, we don't need to maintain a thread for each connections.
This is a huge advantage to use Java TCP NIO.

Whereas in UDP, every packet (datagram) is effectively a self-contained message, each packet could be considered as a request, even we use NIO Datagram channel, we still need to create a thread for each request.

So, what the advantage to use NIO Datagram channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even we use NIO Datagram channel, we still need to create a thread for each request

Why? Not if you're an echo server, a time server, ... it all depends exactly what you're doing.

And you might consider a thread per *client* rather than per request, if your application is such that the clietns keep requesting (as opposed to one-shot requests: time or DNS for example).

Your assumptions don't stand up to scrutiny.

*However* it is certainly true that NIO is oversold and that most applications don't need it. There are servers out there supporting hunreds of thousands of connections in blocking mode.

Comment: Thanks EJP for your response! the server is not a echo server nor time server. when this UDP server receives a UDP packet, it needs to process this packet, and send the processed data to background MQ, then responds the client. Currently this server creates a new thread for each incoming UDP packet to process it. My question is What the advantage and difference if we use NIO datagram channel.

Comment: Little or nothing, according to your description.